# Why doesn't select mode appear in the status line?

Tags: visual-mode, statusline

Regardless of the mode I select, it appears on the status line.

But when I switch to `select` mode, it is not shown on the status line in Vim, whereas it is shown in gVim.

How do I make it work?

Comment: Works here (`v`, move around to select a visual zone, and `<C-g>` to enter select mode) can you provide additional informations?

Comment: Which version/build of vim & which operating system?

Comment: Version 7.2 , Linux

Comment: Are you talking about visual mode (entered via `v`) and miss using the work "select mode" or are you really talking about select mode (entered via `gh`)? In both cases it is pretty weird that only one mode is shown but not the others... Did you follow the steps of this post to be sure that the problem doesn't come from your `.vimrc` http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/1841?